# Desktop fonts in matlab are huge

Tags: matlab, font-size

This problem popped up a couple of days ago with my Matlab install more or less out of the blue as I wasn't installing fonts or fiddling with system settings. Basically, the fonts for the desktop are way too big - I've set all the fonts to size '1' and it's still a little too big for my liking.

Here's an example of what I mean from the Preferences dialog:

[image: Example from Preferences dialog]

All other fonts on the machine are displaying normally, it's only like this in Matlab.

Currently running Linux Mint 11 and the matlab version details are below.

```
>> ver
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MATLAB Version 7.10.0.499 (R2010a)
MATLAB License Number: XXXXXX
Operating System: Linux 2.6.38-8-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 03:31:24 UTC 2011     x86_64
Java VM Version: Java 1.6.0_12-b04 with Sun Microsystems Inc. Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit S    erver VM mixed mode
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem (running CentOS 7) using the following command sequence:

```
xdpyinfo | grep resolution # In my case, 96x96 is what I expect
xrandr --dpi 96x96
# Restart Matlab
```

In my case, my resolution was at 1524x465! I'm running TigerVNC on Windows10. I like to resize my VNC to fit one or both of my screens as well as switch to full screen mode. This operation slowly increases my resolution. In the past, I could see this affect the "Greek" dots that represent my password when unlocking my VNC. That seems to be fixed now since I didn't notice this problem when I launched Matlab.

I found the first hints to this when I ran into [this post](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1338456.html).